# Which library for implementing Oauth in django?

Tags: django

I am developing API using django-tasty-pie and wanted to know which library to implement to get the OAuth working for basing username/password. I want to use this API to do calls from an Android app and a chrome app that would do the user registration. I know about django-social-auth. But I am not exactly dealing with social auth here. Just basic OAuth would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a feel for landscape read this blog post: http://pydanny.com/the-sorry-state-of-python-oauth-providers.html (it also lists all the alternatives).

I looks like Idan's library is most up to date: https://github.com/idan/oauthlib

Comment: Any documentation on how to implement oauthlib in django?

Comment: https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit relies on oauthlib for all the OAuth2 stuff

Answer (score 3):

The post in the accepted answer stated the following at the addendums to the article:

> 07/07/2013 - Please consider
>   https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit for use as a
>   Django-powered OAuth provider. The team behind it is doing it right!